# Force https in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I got a certificate for my site and now I need to move it to https. This is my htaccess:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

How do I do it? Thanks

Comment: This has been asked plenty of times already.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to do it; here's one:

```
## port requirement (bail if not 443)
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
## exceptions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/somepath$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/anotherpath$
## force traffic to https equivalent
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I've added 2 optional RewriteCond entries that allow you to specify exceptions based on the first component of the URI.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'd like to know how to fit the code into the existing one.

Comment: Probly right after the <Files> section (pretty sure that would be the spot for it).

Comment: Experiment, try taking out the optional sections (though they shouldn't matter) and you may have to experiment with the first RewriteCond (I've had mixed results w/ diff versions of apache etc), another option is `%{SERVER_PROTOCOL} !^HTTPS$`, there's a million examples online; I've pulled this sample code from a live server so it works; just enable and disable sections with comments until you settle into something that actually works for you.

Comment: Thanks... well, I posted the question here so that I wouldn't have to experiment and google, but I guess I'll have to do it after all :)

Comment: Do you have Apache listening on both 80 & 443?  You'll need to in order to capture requests on port 80 to be redirected to 443.  You should have 2 vhosts pointing to the same webroot.